# Sidebar does not display on blog page, but fine with static pages

Tags: sidebar, blog

Please help as I am loosing my mind with this issue.

I built my first really simple wordpress theme. http://www.designstest.co.uk/
For NEWS (blog) page I created a new template page-blog.php (based in index.php that is used by all other pages). The only difference - it has sidebar. It works fine if I apply same template to static page, but it does not display sidebar on NEWS(blog) page. If you see CMR page - it has same template applied as NEWS.

I have tried instead of get sidebar just place some simple text and it acts the same - displays text in static pages but not blog.

I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Post the code that displays the sidebar, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Obsolete
```

You have to create the file named `single.php` for your single post template. If you use custom post types, name the file like `single-my_custom_post_type.php`, where `my_custom_post_type` part is your registered custom post type.

Otherwise `index.php` is used by default.

```
-->
```

**Edited**:

You have to change the file name from `page_blog.php` to `page-blog.php`. Notice *dash* and *underscore* in the file name.

See [Single Post display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) in WordPress Codex.

Comment: Thank you for that, but could you please explain what it has to do with the issue? Firstly - if there is no single.php it uses index.php and secondly - It's not the single post page I have issue with. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've missed the point. Temporarily place `<?php echo wp_basename( get_page_template() ); ?>` somewhere in `footer.php` to see the file name of the template used for any page.

Comment: Done it but I don't see it displaying anything on NEWS page, but it does show page-blog.php on CSR page which is correct, NEWS (blog) supposed to use the same template. As it also shows nothing on other pages I assume it means the NEWS(blog) page uses index.php despite the fact I've set it to use page-blog.php. Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Well spotted. Thank you for pointing it out, but problem stays still the same :(

Comment: The last advice is to check dynamic sidebars you've set for your pages.